# Cmake - add_definitions in library - gobally available

Tags: cmake

I have a cmake project with many libraries (standalone additional packages) which are build within my project and then my project is linked against them.

If i have the following ...

```
CMakeLists.txt (1)
main.cpp
main.hpp
library/CMakeLists.txt (2)
library/dummy.cpp
library/dummy.hpp
```

... add have "add_definitions(-DMYDEF=15)" inside the library cmakelists (2). Can i somehow make this available to main.cpp and main.hpp, so they "see" the macro definition which is made inside the lib at preprocessing?
So not only sources/headers within the lib shall work with my definition but also any other dependency, like the main project with main.cpp/main.hpp

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, there is a way; use `target_compile_definitions(mylib PUBLIC MYDEF=15)` for your library, instead of `add_definifions(-DMYDEF=15)`. That way all other targets that are linked against `mylib` will inherit compile definitions from mylib

Please note that `target_compile_definitions` should be added ***after*** the target is created, otherwise, you will receive the error.

Correct usage would be as follows:

```
#add library first
add_library(mylib)

#compile definitions for the target mylib
target_compile_definitions(
  mylib
  PUBLIC
  MYDEF=15
  )
```

More about the subject might be found in cmake documentation for [target_compile_definitions](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_compile_definitions.html)

Comment: sorry just noticed that i ran into trouble implementing this:
In the lib i have: target_compile_definitions(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC -DMYVAR1), where PROJECT_NAME is the lib name. However, i get:  Cannot specify compile definitions for target "libname" which is not built by
  this project.

Comment: there are a couple of reasons this might happen. Most probably you just replaced one statement with the other. However, `target_compile_definitions` may be used _after_ you created the target, i.e. *after* the line `add_library(${PROJECT_NAME} ...)`

Comment: Aaah thanks. Ya the order was bad, if i put it after add_lib then it works.